# PIL. Ухудшение качества картинки

Tags: python, изображения

я создаю генератор мемов (а именно, пикч). В Image.save() аргумент quality - не то, что мне нужно! Нужно, что бы мем был плохого качества как на картинке. Как возможно такое реализовать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через аргумент quality. Почему не то?

Comment: Почему-то при просмотре превью картинки, получается вот такое: https://ibb.co/MVVDZvz

Comment: Ну, сделайте шрифт побольше, как в вашем примере

Comment: @CrazyElf стоп, простите, если это так, но может это проблема в том, что вк сам сжимает привью фото? Просто с моим примером в вк разницы нет, превью или полный просмотр